# Magento 2: -How to get product reviews, each review with a star

Tags: magento2, review, object-manager

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

$collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter(
    $currentStoreId
    )->addStatusFilter(
    \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
    )->addEntityFilter(
    'product',
    $product->getId()
    )->setDateOrder();
    $reviewlist = $collection->getData();
    foreach ($reviewlist as $review) 
    {
        echo "<pre/>";
        print_r($review);
    }
```

**#######################################################**

```
Output
    [review_id] => 
    [created_at] => 
    [entity_id] => 
    [entity_pk_value] => 
    [status_id] => 
    [detail_id] => 
    [title] => 
    [detail] => 
    [nickname] => 
    [customer_id] => 
    [entity_code] =>
```

**In that I can not get the review star per review with the help of object manager.**
[image]
**I want highlighted box value**

Comment: first of all, objectmanager is a bad idea to implement.

Comment: I know that, but can you help with my issue?@ShyamKrishnaSreekumar

Comment: you can try with [magento 2 product reviews](https://www.mageants.com/advanced-product-reviews-for-magento-2.html) extension it will easy to install and resolve your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> I found one link that helps to get a collection of each review
> ```

```
    <?php 
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;  
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';  
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);  
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();  
    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');  
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');  

    $reviewId = 5; //custom review id.  
    $ratingCollection = $obj->get('Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Option\Vote\Collection')
                       ->addRatingInfo()
                       ->addOptionInfo()
                       ->addRatingOptions()
                       ->addFieldToFilter('review_id',$reviewId);  
    print_r($ratingCollection->getData());
```

Answer (score 4):

> Try to use bellow code in your phtml file You should not use the ObjectManager directly!

```
<?php
$productId = 'your_product_id';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$storeManager  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
$reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
?>
<?php if($ratingSummary){ ?>
<div class="product-reviews-summary short">
    <div class="rating-summary">
        <div title="<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
            <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$ratingSummary; ?>%</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviews-actions">
        <?php echo __('('.$reviewCount.') Reviews'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I used this code and get an overall rating amount, but i want individual rating value and also updated question.@Chander Shekhar

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `$collection->load()->addRateVotes();`, than get ratings 
 for each review by calling `$review->getRatingVotes();`